# Laravel - How to call static function without instantiate object

Tags: php, laravel, oop, model-view-controller, web

Is there any way in Laravel (5.2) to call static and/or non-static function in a custom object without having to instantiate the referring object in all classes it is used?

Example: I have class `App\Helpers\Utilities.php` with public function `doBeforeTask()`

I'm using this method in allot of classes within my project and it would be pretty if i could just call `Utilities::doBeforeTask()` or `Utilities->doBeforeTask()` without creating a instance of my Utilities object `$obj = new Utilities();`

Comment: Wouldn't renaming it to `public static function doBeforeTask()` accomplish exactly what you need?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

define your method as static method. and call it anywhere with following code:

```
Utilities::doBeforeTask();
```

Code structure of file **App\Helpers\Utilities.php**

```
namespace App\Library;

class Utilities {

 //added new user
 public static function doBeforeTask() {
  // ... you business logic.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Define your method as a static method. and call it anywhere

let's take an example

```
 namespace App\Http\Utility;

    class ClassName{

        public static function methodName(){
         // ... you business logic.
        }
    }
```

where you want to use specify the namespace

like this:

```
use App\Http\Utility\ClassName;

ClassName::methodName();
```

**Don't forget to run**

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a method that you cannot change to static (i.e. it's a vendor file) then you can do this in PHP >= 5.4

```
$something = (new Something)->foo("bar");
```

Answer (score 1):

Define static function

```
class Foo
{

    public static function staticFunction() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

now call Foo::staticFunction()

Comment: But does it not require some sort of autoload or implementation in composer.json such as service provider or alias?

Comment: If  you want to use it everywhere you can either require it in the autoload or add it as dep in composer

Comment: Not sure if you're supposed to create it but there is no app/helpers folder in Laravel 6.

Comment: @boomdrak, no not in this case, because it's simple plain PHP implementation. All that is required for autoloading is ofcourse the psr-4 compliant namespace. What you are thinking of is Laravel's Facade.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel also has a Facade implementation, which is probably what TS had in mind. These Facades will do basically everything for you and most likely also solves the "vendor-file" issue.

https://www.larashout.com/creating-custom-facades-in-laravel

basically you have to provide an instance of it and point your facade to it, which in turn get's an alias you register. everything is explained in above url.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic static calls

```
Utilities::anyMethod($args);
```

PHP code

```
<?php
namespace App\Library;

class Utilities {
  public function anyMethod() {
     // simple code
  }

  public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
  {
      $instance = static::resolveFacadeInstance(static::getFacadeAccessor());
      switch (count($args))
      {
        case 0:
            return $instance->$method();

        case 1:
            return $instance->$method($args[0]);

        case 2:
            return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1]);

        case 3:
            return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);

        case 4:
            return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);

        default:
            return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);
      }
    }
  }
}
```